# How to check will the method work in concurrent environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to understand multithreading.
I have the class and method which looks like:

```
public class Tree {

    ConcurrentHashMap<String, Apple> concurrentHashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Apple>();
/*This method should ONCE (@Before in jUnit4)create an array of apples*/
    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, Apple> getTreeApples(int NumOfApples) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfApples; i++) {
            String appleNum = "5" + String.format("%010d", i);

            concurrentHashMap.put(appleNum, new Apple(appleNum, Long.valueOf("10")));
        }
        return concurrentHashMap;

    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

/*This method get apple weight from array using different thread from the pool above*/
    public Long getAppleWeight (String appleNum) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        Long weight = null;
        Callable<Long> task = () -> {
            System.out.println("Thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            return concurrentHashMap.get(appleNum).getWeight();};

        Future<Long> future = executor.submit(task);

        weight = future.get();
        System.out.println("Apple " + appleNum  + " weight is " + weight);
        return weight ;
    }
}
```

I can't understand:

1. Is getAppleWeight method suitable to work in multithreading environment?
2. Will it work correctly in multithreading environment (when method getAppleWeight will be called by two different systems in the same time)?
3. How to check (test) it (call it by two separate systems)?

Comment: I see potential for a thread to re-assign `concurrentHashMap` from another thread before `getAppleWeight` has a chance to access it - might wanna prevent threads from accessing the map until that method is complete. But really, it depends on your environment. Do other threads attempt to reassign that variable?

Comment: concurrentHashMap should be created once. we work with only one array in the memory. but we may add a new element to it.